# How can I use a loop with an iterator in order to evaluate a function?

Tags: function-construction, iterators

I'm trying to evaluate a function, that depends on two variables, in a specific set of values. I will write an example, but my system is more complicated.

```
f[x_,y_]:= x^2+y;
```

x and y must be valued for the following list of data:

```
x={1,2,3,4};
y={0,1,2,5};
```

The thing is that I need to evaluate f[x,y] for each pair of coordinates [x,y]:

```
{{1,0},{2,1},{3,2},{4,5}}
```

with the help of a loop, for example Do. This, because my system is more complicated and I can not do it manually (It will take me a lot of time). I was trying to use the loop Do with the iterator Thread, nonetheless I don´t know if this is possible .

I'm new using Mathematica. I really don't understand why this is happening. Some of you guys can help me? Thank you.

Comment: If you only need to input pairs where the x and y values have the same index position in the list, you could use `Table[f[x[[i]], y[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[x]}]`.  (This wouldn't iterate over all possible ordered pairs of elements from the lists x and y.)

Comment: `f @@@ Transpose[{x, y}]`. Look up [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html). The `@@@` is a shortcut for "Apply at level 1".

Comment: just use `f[x,y]` , that is, `x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
y = {0, 1, 2, 5};f[x, y]` (because `f` as defined is a `Listable` function). For an arbitrary function `g[u,v]` defined for ordered pair `{u,v}` you can give it the attribute `Listable` using `SetAttributes[g, Listable]` to make it automatically thread over its arguments so that  for lists `ul` and `vl` of the same length, you can simply use `g[ul, vl]`.

Comment: @TimWagner  Thank you. That works!

Answer (score 12):

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4};
y = {0, 1, 2, 5};
```

#### [Listable >> Properties and Relations](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html):

> ***"A function implemented in terms of a listable operation may not need the Listable attribute:"***

Since `f` is defined in terms of [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) operations (`Plus` and `Power`) it automatically threads over list arguments. So you can simply use `f[x,y]` for list inputs `x` and `y`:

```
f[x_,y_] := x^2+y
f[x,y]
```

> {1, 5, 11, 21}

In general, you can use

#### 1. [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)

```
ClearAll[foo]
Thread[foo[x,y]]
```

> {foo[1, 0], foo[2, 1], foo[3, 2], foo[4, 5]}

#### 2. [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) + [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html)

```
ClearAll[foo]
foo @@@ Thread[{x, y}]
```

> {foo[1, 0], foo[2, 1], foo[3, 2], foo[4, 5]}

#### 3. [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html)

```
MapThread[foo, {x, y}]
```

> {foo[1, 0], foo[2, 1], foo[3, 2], foo[4, 5]}

#### 4. [`SetAttributes`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetAttributes.html) + [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html):

```
ClearAll[foo]
SetAttributes[foo, Listable]
foo[x, y]
```

> {foo[1, 0], foo[2, 1], foo[3, 2], foo[4, 5]}

Comment: Very educational answer.  It is interesting but not intuitive that f is listable, yet as you say, it works.  I've tried Attributes[f] and "?f" to see what it says.  How would we know that f is listable?

Comment: @MarkR, although `f` does not have any attributes it is effectively `Listable` since `FullForm[f[x,y]` is `Plus[Power[x, 2], y]` and  both `Power` and `Plus` are `Listable`.

Comment: Nice answer. MapThread is the most obvious one to understand. The others are a bit non-obvious.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know why it is listable - this makes complete sense.