# How can I evaluate a matrix for a set of values?

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to evaluate a system, that depends on two variables, in a specific set of values. I will write an example, but my system is more complicated.

```
H = {{x^2, y}, {y^2, x}};
{val, vect} = Eigensystem[H];
```

I select an  eigenvector

```
b = vect[[1]];
```

Then I write new variables in terms of the eigenvector elements

```
A = b[[1]];
B = b[[2]];
```

Finally, a new matrix is built.

```
M = {{A, B}, {A*A, B}};
```

x and y must be evaluate for the following list of data:

```
x={1,2,3,4};
y={0,1,2,5};
```

The thing is that I need to find the matrix M for each pair of coordinates [x,y]:

```
{{1,0},{2,1},{3,2},{4,5}}
```

with the help of a loop, for example Do. This, because my system is more complicated and I can not do it manually (It will take me a lot of time). I was trying to use the loop Do with the iterator Thread, nonetheless I don´t know if this is possible .

I'm new using Mathematica. I really don't understand why this is happening. Some of you guys can help me? Thank you.

Comment: Programmatically, this is the same problem as the problem in another recent question of yours, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/215466/how-can-i-use-a-loop-with-an-iterator-in-order-to-evalueate-a-function.  You could define a function that has a matrix value in the ways shown in the linked Q&A.

Comment: And never define a variable starting with an upper-case letter as it can conflict with *Mathematica*'s internal names.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of possible way to do this; which is preferable is likely to depend on your specific needs.  One method is to form a [`Function`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) and then [`MapThread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapThread.html) that across your values.  Below [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html) is used to get the definition of `M` into the held `Function` body instead of a verbatim `M`.

```
Clear[x, y]

MapThread[{x, y} \[Function] Evaluate[M], {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 5}}] // Quiet
```

> ```
> {{{Indeterminate, 1}, {Indeterminate, 1}},
>  {{1/2 (2 - 2 Sqrt[2]), 1}, {1/4 (-2 + 2 Sqrt[2])^2, 1}},
>  {{1/8 (6 - 2 Sqrt[17]), 1}, {1/64 (-6 + 2 Sqrt[17])^2, 1}},
>  {{1/50 (12 - 2 Sqrt[161]), 1}, {(-12 + 2 Sqrt[161])^2/2500, 1}}}
> ```

Another method is to make a [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) function to handle the threading directly, as follows:

```
fn = Function[{x, y}, Evaluate[M], Listable];

fn[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 5}] // Quiet   (* same output *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility

```
ClearAll[x, y];
H = {{x^2, y}, {y^2, x}};
v = First@Eigenvectors[H];
A = v[[1]]; B = v[[2]];
M = {{A, B}, {A*A, B}};
xCoord = {1, 2, 3, 4};
yCoord = {0, 1, 2, 5};
coord = Partition[Riffle[xCoord, yCoord], 2];
data = {{#[[1]], #[[2]]}, Limit[M, {x -> #[[1]], y -> #[[2]]}]} & /@ coord;
data = {#[[1]], MatrixForm[#[[2]]]} & /@ data;
Grid[Join[{{"(x,y)", "M matrix"}}, data], Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want numerical, change the line above to

```
 data = {#[[1]], MatrixForm[N@#[[2]]]} & /@ data;
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Two things to note are (1) different eigenvector normalization would lead to different M-matrices and (2) when $(x,y)=(1,0)$ we have two eigenvectors for the repeated eigenvalue, so which eigenvector do we call "first"?  We let Mathematica choose the normalization and the eigenvector order in the following code:

```
H = {{x^2, y}, {y^2, x}};
allM = Table[
   With[{v = First@Eigenvectors[
        H /. x -> First@val /. y -> Last@val]},
    {v, v*{First@v, 1}}],
   {val, Thread[{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 5}}]}];

Column[MatrixForm /@ allM]
```

$\begin{array}{l}
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1+\sqrt{2} & 1 \\
 \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)^2 & 1
   \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{4}
   \left(3+\sqrt{17}\right) &
   1 \\
 \frac{1}{16}
   \left(3+\sqrt{17}\right)^2
   & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
 \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{1}{25}
   \left(6+\sqrt{161}\right) &
   1 \\
 \frac{1}{625}
   \left(6+\sqrt{161}\right)^2
   & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right) \\
\end{array}$

The reason these results differ from other methods is that this method puts the numbers in first so Mathematica can use numeric sort.

When $(x,y)=(1,0)$ the H-matrix is the identity matrix, so any finite, non-zero vector ${A,B}$ is an eigenvector.